# How to fix More than one scoped css files were found for the razor component for Razor Component

Tags: css, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

This is what my project looks like:
[image]

I have just css file for my razor component, but when I try to build it I get the `More than one scoped css files were found for the razor component 'Pages\Randomizer\RandomizeNamesAdvanced.razor'. Each razor component must have at most a single associated scoped css file.`  error.

I copied pasted the css file from another component's css file if that makes any difference. But I have checked both the css file's build action is set to Content. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

**Update (Solution 1)**

I faced the problem again after I renamed a .razor file. The problem is in the .csproj file. Make sure you have your .css file name with a remove property.

[image]

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Pages\Randomizer\NameCard.razor.css" />
    <None Remove="Pages\Randomizer\RandomizeNamesMedium.razor.css" />    <== this line was missing
    <None Remove="Pages\Randomizer\RandomizeNamesBasic.razor.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Pages\Randomizer\NameCard.razor.css" />
    <Content Include="Pages\Randomizer\RandomizeNamesMedium.razor.css" />   <== this is the file I renamed
    <Content Include="Pages\Randomizer\RandomizeNamesBasic.razor.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If this still doesn't fix the issue you can follow solution 2 which is basically re-adding the file.

---

**Solution 2**

Not sure what was causing the issue, but I ended up just deleting the file and adding it back again. Would still like to know if someone knows a better solution without deleting the file.

Note: after adding the style sheet the build action was set to None, had to change it to Content manually.

Comment: Have you change compilation/intermediate targets? Or moved files around, maybe a copy existed in the old path but wasn't in the project?

Comment: I have a personal rule to prevent problems like this.  Never copy razor stuff within VS.  Do it outside VS.  I do it in file explorer.  VS then picks up the changes and renaming correctly and doesn't get itself in a twist!

Comment: I solved this by removing the ItemGroup properties altogether.

Comment: I too moved the a file. Renaming didn't work. Deleting and re-creating didn't work. The cause of my problem was that I was creating the style sheet by creating a new razor component and then renaming to mycomponent.razor.css. What worked was to create a new style sheet and naming it mycomponent.razor.css. What seemed to confuse the compiler was trying to turn a component into a style sheet by renaming the file extension.